# What are the differences between floating point Equals and the Equality operator (==) in C#?

Tags: c#, comparison, nan, equality

In C#, [`Single.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.equals?view=net-5.0)

> Returns a value indicating whether two instances of Single represent the same *value*.

While Single's [`Equality operator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators) (`==`)

> The equality operator == returns true if its operands *are equal*, false otherwise.

(emphasis mine).

One notable difference between these comparison methods involves NaN:

```
float.NaN.Equals(float.NaN) => true
float.NaN == float.NaN => false
```

I understand why `operator==` is false between NaNs (answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)), but why is `Equals` different? Are there other values for which `Equals` provides a different result than `operator==`?